# find the transition matrix from $T$ to $S$ when $S=\{u,v\}$ and $T=\{u-v,u+2v\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Usually when I do this kind of finding transition matrix questions, there will be numbers given for $S$ and $T$. Hence, I am not sure how to proceed when the question now gives in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the matrix at the left you have:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\1&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
u-v\\u+2v
\end{bmatrix}
$$